# How to change app store Preview Language option

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

My app is on App store & there is no localization as I can see in Code (Plz see attached image below)

[image]

But when I looked app on App store page I can see there are two languages (English, Icelandic) see below

[image]

I have Mapbox & OneSingle third-party library in the code but don't think I am getting Icelandic because of them.

Please suggest how to remove Icelandic from app store preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your project settings:

[image]

You may have some resource in your project (storyboard/asset/other file) that may have been localised by mistake.

More info on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html).